# problem in action listener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I want to use this example   http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20425
but there is a problem, I dont know how to write action listener for my buttons, I mean I know but where ?

please advice me.
I place above example here.

If you have any better example please inform me also...

```
    import com.sun.java.swing.*;
import com.sun.java.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
  private TableCellRenderer __defaultRenderer;

  public JTableButtonRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
    __defaultRenderer = renderer;
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                         boolean isSelected,
                         boolean hasFocus,
                         int row, int column)
  {
    if(value instanceof Component)
      return (Component)value;
    return __defaultRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
       table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
  }
}

class JTableButtonModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private Object[][] __rows = {
      { "One", new JButton("Button One") },
      { "Two", new JButton("Button Two") },
      { "Three", new JButton("Button Three") },
      { "Four", new JButton("Button Four") }
    };

  private String[] __columns = { "Numbers", "Buttons" };

  public String getColumnName(int column) { 
    return __columns[column];
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return __rows.length;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return __columns.length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) { 
      return __rows[row][column];
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
  }
}

class JTableButtonMouseListener implements MouseListener {
  private JTable __table;

  private void __forwardEventToButton(MouseEvent e) {
    TableColumnModel columnModel = __table.getColumnModel();
    int column = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
    int row    = e.getY() / __table.getRowHeight();
    Object value;
    JButton button;
    MouseEvent buttonEvent;

    if(row >= __table.getRowCount() || row < 0 ||
       column >= __table.getColumnCount() || column < 0)
      return;

    value = __table.getValueAt(row, column);

    if(!(value instanceof JButton))
      return;

    button = (JButton)value;

    buttonEvent =
      (MouseEvent)SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(__table, e, button);
    button.dispatchEvent(buttonEvent);
    // This is necessary so that when a button is pressed and released
    // it gets rendered properly.  Otherwise, the button may still appear
    // pressed down when it has been released.
    __table.repaint();
  }

  public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table) {
    __table = table;
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    __forwardEventToButton(e);
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    __forwardEventToButton(e);
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    __forwardEventToButton(e);
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    __forwardEventToButton(e);
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    __forwardEventToButton(e);
  }
}

public final class JTableButton extends JFrame {
  private JTable __table;
  private JScrollPane __scrollPane;

  public JTableButton() {
    super("JTableButton Demo");
    TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer;

    __table = new JTable(new JTableButtonModel());
    defaultRenderer = __table.getDefaultRenderer(JButton.class);
    __table.setDefaultRenderer(JButton.class,
                   new JTableButtonRenderer(defaultRenderer));
    __table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    __table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(__table));

    __scrollPane = new JScrollPane(__table);
    setContentPane(__scrollPane);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame;
    WindowListener exitListener;

    exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    Window window = e.getWindow();
    window.setVisible(false);
    window.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
      }
    };

    frame = new JTableButton();
    frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    new JButton("Button One").addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

This is the easiest way. You can also create a regular class that implements `ActionListener` interface and pass its object to `addActionListener` method. In this sample I used Anonymous Class.

Your code goes into `actionPerformed` method. It will be executed when someone clicks the button.

Comment: I can not do that here!because it think I call a void function but it need object!

Comment: Im sorry, I just pasted an example how you would normally make it. The error your IDE shows (i.e. Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Object) exists because you pass the addActionListener return value as a new table element instead of JButton when you add my code. What you need to do is first create the JButtons outside of the table, add actionListeners and then add the JButtons to the table just like in second code block provided by Dhruv Gairola.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
class JTableButtonModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private Object[][] __rows = {
      { "One", new JButton("Button One") },
      { "Two", new JButton("Button Two") },
      { "Three", new JButton("Button Three") },
      { "Four", new JButton("Button Four") }
    };
```

write

```
class JTableButtonModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   JButton b1 = new JButton("Button One");
   JButton b2 = new JButton("Button Two");
   JButton b3 = new JButton("Button Three");
   JButton b4 = new JButton("Button Four");
   //do this for all buttons
   b1.setActionCommand("b1");
   b1.addActionListener(this);
   //....do this for b2, b3 and b4
   private Object[][] __rows = {
      { "One", b1 },
      { "Two", b2},
      { "Three", b3 },
      { "Four", b4}
   };
   //the rest of the code
}
```

you will then need to implement ActionListener and override the actionPerformed method like so:

```
    //detect the ActionEvents and handle accordingly
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //gets the action command
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        //if Button One was clicked
        if("b1".equals(cmd)) {
           //do something
        }
     //... do this for all buttons
    }
```

note that the link you presented is not a great example for whatever you are trying to accomplish.

**EDIT:**

as for your question about actionPerformed being a void, please note that in this function, you merely detect the event and which button was caused it. then, in the respective `if` statement, you can manipulate your objects as necessary by calling some method which takes an object e.g.

```
   //if Button One was clicked
   if("b1".equals(cmd)) {
      Object doSomethingWithB1();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you have any better example please inform me also...

Maybe, [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)